# Implementing jQuery hoverZoom in AngularJS ng-Repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to implement [jQuery hoverZoom](http://jmar.github.io/jquery-hoverZoom/) in my project. It works fine in a normal html jquery app but when i try to run it in angular app using ng-repeat it breaks.

My guess is due to DOM & jQuery. I think I have to create a directive or something.

The working code is:

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/zoom_style.css?v=2">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.hoverZoom.css">



        <ul class="thumb">

            <li><a href="../api/uploads/bjaim/1.jpg"><img alt="Images can have captions" src="../api/uploads/bjaim/1_thumb.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li class="noborder"><a href="../api/uploads/bjaim/2.jpg"><img alt="zoomContainer can be styled with CSS" src="../api/uploads/bjaim/2_thumb.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li class="redshadow"><a href="../api/uploads/bjaim/3.jpg"><img src="../api/uploads/bjaim/3_thumb.jpg" alt="Images are scaled and centered to the viewport" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="../api/uploads/bjaim/bigimage.jpg"><img src="../api/uploads/bjaim/bigimage_thumb.jpg" alt="Images are preloaded and then the animation starts"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="../api/uploads/bjaim/5.jpg"><img src="../api/uploads/bjaim/5_thumb.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="../api/uploads/bjaim/6.jpg"><img src="../api/uploads/bjaim/6_thumb.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="../api/uploads/bjaim/7.jpg"><img src="../api/uploads/bjaim/7_thumb.jpg" /></a></li> 

        </ul>
```

Javascript

```
<script src="assets/js/modernizr-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.hoverZoom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.thumb img').hoverZoom({speedView:600, speedRemove:400, showCaption:true, speedCaption:600, debug:true, hoverIntent: true, loadingIndicatorPos: 'center'});
    });  
</script>
```

But when I chnage the HTML to:

```
<ul class="thumb">
             <li ng-repeat="image in images">
                 <a ng-href="../api/uploads/{{job}}/{{image}}"><img alt="Images can have captions"  ng-src="../api/uploads/{{job}}/{{image}}" /></a>

            </li>
        </ul>
```

It displays the images but hover effect is gone.

Please guide.

Not: Tried to replicate the code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vishsid73/3aM7G/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to create a directive,

```
 .directive('hoverZoom', function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element){
           $(element).hoverZoom({speedView:600, speedRemove:400, showCaption:true, speedCaption:600, debug:true, hoverIntent: true, loadingIndicatorPos: 'center'});
       }
    };
  });
```

And in HTML,

```
  <a hover-zoom ng-href="../api/uploads/{{job}}/{{image}}"><img alt="Images can have captions"  ng-src="../api/uploads/{{job}}/{{image}}" /></a>
```

Depending on your requirement you can try to improve this directive to pass the options for `hoverZoom` as well. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: I tried your solution. Now the pictures are not showing up at all. They are invisible. And if I move mouse around the area, on console it shows function centerImage(), mouseleave, function zoomOut.

Comment: I am building a jsfiddle to try. Please guide me

Comment: I don´t know much about angular, but it seems your ng-repeat isn´t working. The image path is missing in the output. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/jmartsch/3aM7G/5/