# javascript not working after pageload

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to UI development. I am using AngularJs in my project. I have configured the routes, controllers inside a module and referencing the same inside the html page. The controller is responsible for embedding a carousel inside a `ng-view` `div` tag of the main html page. Till this it is working fine but the carousel has jquery scripts which I have placed in the main html page. The script is responsible for populating the contents of the slider. I want the script tag on the html page to be run once the page loads the partials containing the carousel and not before the partial is included and displayed. Currently when I inspect using the firebug, the script is getting executed before the partial section is included and none of the script tags related to the partial section are working after the page renders. Kindly let me know where I am going wrong or how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `onload` event in the `ng-view` to exacute your jquery DOM manipulation .`onload` event will fire after the content HTML is loaded. [Read the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView)

Comment: I got this working. but If I use the onload attribute then I need to put my javascript code inside the controller. The script code is jquery and not normal javascript. How to tackle this?

Comment: `The script code is jquery and not normal javascript` but Still you can put this inside the onload event in the controller. But best method to solve this issue is to create your carousel directive.

Comment: Have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234274/implementing-jquery-hoverzoom-in-angularjs-ng-repeat/23234420#23234420

Comment: Is creating a custom directive the best approach to take? Also if I create a custom carousel directive, will I be able to call jquery script?